# Get the background color of a widget - really

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm having trouble getting the actual background color of widgets.
In my special case I'm having trouble with widgets within a QTabWidget.

This is on Windows7.
So classic widgets have some greyish background, whereas widgets within a tab are generally drawn with a white background.

I tried:

```
def bgcolor(widget):
    color = widget.palette().color(widget.backgroundRole()) # version 1
    color = widget.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Background) # version 2
    rgba = color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), color.alpha()
    return rgba
```

which is pretty much what I could figure out myself from the Qt documentation and what google and SO give.
But, this just doesn't work.

I'm testing widgets inside and outside of a TabWidget and the function above returns identical colors for obviously differently colored widgets.
Namely it always returns the greyish color, even for the plain white colored widgets within the tab.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

My problem is when using matplotlib, matplotlib draws figures with a "none" facecolor with the wrong background color when embedded in a QTabWidget: grey, even though the parent widget is white.

To fix this I wanted to get the background color of the widget and set it as background color for the figure.
Though this may be a matplotlib issue, I guessed this would be the quickest workaround.
As I noticed I couldn't get the proper color, I became insistent :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The palette is returning the correct colours.

The mistake you're probably making is that you're assuming "background" always means the same thing for all widgets. Let's take an unmodified `QListWidget` as an example. On a desktop with a traditional light-coloured scheme, this will probably appear as a white viewport inside a 3D sunken panel. But if you query the "background" for this widget, you will see something like this:

```
>>> widget = QtGui.QListWidget()
>>> widget.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Background).name()
'#edecec'
```

which is obviously not white. So `Background` is the wrong color role to query for this widget. Instead, it looks like `Base` might be more appropriate:

```
>>> widget.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Base).name()
'#ffffff'
```

It's worth noting that the [documentation for color roles](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) states that `Background` and `Foreground` are obsolete values, with `Window` and `WindowText` being recommended instead. Perhaps this is because the former terms are now considered to be misleading.

**UPDATE**:

On platforms which use pixmap-based styling, some of the reported palette colours will not match the visual appearance of a widget. This issue specifically affects Windows and OSX, and so may explain why you are not able to get the apparent background colour of tabs. This issue is documented in a [Qt FAQ](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#Why_does_nothing_happen_when_I_set_the_palette_background_color_on_a_QPushButton_in_some_styles.3F), which also gives some possible solutions (although the `QProxyStyle` option is supported in PyQt5 but not PyQt4).

Comment: 'Base' would however be wrong for all widgets outside the tab. I was hoping that 'QWidget::backgroundRole()' would give the correct color role enum for each widget.. can only check once i'm back in the office...

Comment: In other words - I was hoping that `QWidget::backgroundRole()` would resolve this ambiguity in version 1 of my `bgcolor`, ideally returning e.g. `Base` or `Window` as appropriate. But it apparently does not... me trying to figure out the correct role for a widget in its current parent seems unlikely to me to be the "correct" solution.

Comment: @sebastian. It would help if you explained what you wanted to do with this information - what's your actual use-case?

Comment: @sebastian. I've updated my answer with some additional information which seems to identify your issue. It looks like it might be worth experimenting with stylesheets to see if you can get the result you are after.

Comment: Having read the FAQ: not being able to change the color, does not necessarily mean its impossible to get the color too, right?! Anyway, I managed to get the correct color using `QPixmap::grabWidget`, which seems somewhat overkill though. So I went back to a quick&dirty non-generic fix and set the matplotlib figure's color to `white` manually for the being...